# FormData parameters not pass to server with AJAX (pass fine with XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax to pass a file (for upload it to server) and some other parameters to the server (perl cgi) but the server doesn't get the parameters.

The ajax:

```
$(function() {
    $('#upload_file').click(function (){
        var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        formdata.append("sid", "1234");
        formdata.append("file", file);
        formdata.append("file_path_on_server", "/path/");
        formdata.append("local_file_name", "sidebar_custom.css");
        formdata.append("add_timestamp", "1"); // add timestamp to file name

        $.ajax({
            url : 'upload_file.cgi',
            type : 'POST',
            data : formdata,
            processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
            }
        });

        // var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // xhr.open("POST","upload_file.cgi",true);
        // if (xhr.status != 200) {
        //  alert("Error '" + xhr.status + "' occurred when trying to upload your file.");
        // }            
        // xhr.send(formdata);

    });
});
```

When I am using `XMLHttpRequest` instead (which commented out) all parameters pass to the server script as requested.
e.g.
I tried to print the parameter "sid" but it is empty with `ajax` and "1234" with  `XMLHttpRequest`.

I don't want to use `XMLHttpRequest` because I can't receive respond from the server (e.g. some file name string).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can receive a response with XMLHttpRequest... what do you think jQuery's Ajax is under the covers....

Comment: So look at the developer console, what do you see in the network request when the Ajax call is made?

Comment: 1. Can you please point me to some example on how to receive such data? (couldn't find).

Comment: You are using XMLHttpRequest url: upload_file.cgi but for Ajax url: my_script.cgi . Any difference in the server side methods like supported HTTP verbs, parameter names etc between those two methods?

Comment: @Mike look at onreadystatechange or onload Look at MDN

Comment: Sorry Siva Gopal,  it was a type. script name is 'upload_file.cgi'

Comment: This would probably go easier, if you didn’t try and assemble the form data yourself. If you pass a reference to a form element as parameter to the constructor, it will take care of creating the relevant data and -structure to send all by itself. So I’d rather put the additional parameters you need to submit into the form a hidden fields, pass the form to the FormData constructor, and then just send the result of that.

Comment: CBroe, do you mean just to use `var formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById('myForm2'));`? if yes, it still doesn't pass parameters (e.g. 'sid')

Comment: I debug it in developer mode and it looks that `formdata` is empty.
Probably for `XMLHttpRequest ` the parameters comes from the form itself and not from and not from `formdata`. However, it seems that this ajax solution even if it worked on my firefox, it is not supported by I.E9 (only 10+) so it is problematic for me.